# set conditional formatting - bottom edge

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to set conditional formatting for the range when $B2<>$B3. Here is my code:

```
Sub AddBorders()
Dim rng As Range
If ActiveSheet.Name <> Sheet1.Name Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rng = Range(Range("A2").End(xlToRight), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
'rng.Activate
rng.FormatConditions.Delete


With rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlNotEqual, "=$B2<>$B3")
    With rng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Looks like the border has been added at the very bottom of the range, what I would like to have is the border within the range when the values in column B are different . When I click on "Conditional Formatting" I see formatting has been set and adding it by hand in "Format" -> "Border" -> setting bottom border does exactly what I want. But I don't know how to code it properly.

Comment: your rng only gets the last column of your range... see if the data ends on column C and row 500, your range is C2:C500 not sure if that's the range you want to format. On the other hand, when you select such range and do the edgebottom border, it will only paint the C500. You need to use the Borders(xlInsideHorizontal) to get the ones in between

Comment: I think you just have to remove `rng` from `With rng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)`  but I'll check.

Comment: Are you trying to set conditional formatting for range: **A2 to last column and last row**?

Comment: @Damian, thanks. Your solution makes border after each row (even if $B2=$B3") and this is not what I would like to have. I do not understand how to 'touch' the format section of conditional formatting. Looks like this approach totally ignores it and sets traditional borders which are erasable from 'Borders' menu.

Comment: @Damian, actually it gets the range("C2:A500") which excel's overhead interprets as range("A2:C500").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take rng away so you are setting the borders of the conditional formatting and swap xlEdgeBottom out for xlBottom.

```
Sub AddBorders()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A2").End(xlToRight), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    End With

    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B2<>$B3")
            With .Borders(xlBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you sir.